# Where does Rick Sanchez park his spacecraft?

Tags: rick-and-morty

It can't be in the garage since Rick lives/creates there. It can't be in the backyard since we never see it there.

The only assumption I have is that his underground vault has some kind of parking bay which is accessible from the street level.

**Is it confirmed somewhere where Rick parks his spaceship**?

Comment: That raises a follow-up question, where do Jerry/Beth park their cars? I think in both cases I've seen them park in the driveway, but in general it seems their vehicles disappear when not important to the scene.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh: When Jerry was loading the car/truck (I forget) when moving out, he parked it in front of the house, on the roadside. [Beth and Jerry also didn't park in the driveway in the S1 finale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfTFEtfKi_4) (visible at 0:39). So it seems that Rick has claimed the garage and driveway for himself (which seems in character for Rick to claim it, Beth to allow Rick to do so, and Jerry to fail at convincing Beth that it's unfair)

Comment: @Flater now that you mention it, my memory of Beth parking in the driveway might have been from a simulation.

Answer (score 10):

It's never explicitly shown nor confirmed, so any answer is speculative at best.

Rick does have plenty of options:

- There is a vast underground laboratory under the garage, and the garage floor itself is a huge loading bay.
- Rick has a portal gun. He could literally park his UFO anywhere and access it by portal.
- Rick is seen parking his UFO in the street and not really caring about leaving it in a public place (probably because of the inbuilt defense system), so it's possible that Rick doesn't even care about hiding the UFO from sight.
- Rick is able to shrink objects (cfr Anatomy Park), it's not impossible that he shrinks the UFO down to a more manageable size.